# css3 diamond shape with hover animation

Tags: css, animation, shapes

I have used CSS3 diamond shape for the below HTML Code but this is not cover my requirement i need diamond shape and hover animation, check my code

```css
  img.clip { 
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 78%, 0 0, 100% 0); 
  clip-path: polygon(50% 78%, 0 0, 100% 0);
}
  
img.tclip { 
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 50% 90%, 50% 90%, 0 100%); 
    clip-path: polygon(100% 100%, 50% 90%, 50% 90%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
  <a href="#"> 
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" 
    class="tclip"/>
   <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" 
    class="clip"/>
</a>
```

Comment: As it is now, it is not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve. Please help us understand the expect final result.

Comment: Kindly check the link https://jsfiddle.net/434496yd/

Comment: i need hover animation

Comment: What have you tried? I see absolutely no hover in your code.

Comment: i have tried 3d animation on hover but its not working

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add an hover animation, you can use css like this

```
#diamond{
  transition: 3s all;
}
#diamond:hover {
  opacity: 0.5; //here your second state, on hover
}
```

with this html

```
<a href="#" id="diamond">
```

or maybe you want the animation of a real diamond turning ?

Comment: Thanks for giving code , i will check and update you